# How can I display multiple column records in the same row?

Tags: database-design, sqlite3

I want to display all related information in to the same row column. Currently my output and query are the following:

| Trader | Items |
| --- | --- |
| Prapor | Weapons |
| Prapor | Wearables |
| Prapor | Weapon Modifications |
| Prapor | Health and Buffs |
| Therapist | Weapons |
| Therapist | Wearables |
| Therapist | Weapon Modifications |
| Therapist | Health and Buffs |

```
select NPC_Traders.Nickname as Trader, Classes.Class as Items
from NPC_Traders, Classes
where Items IN (
           select npc.Tradeables
           from NPC_Traders npc 
           where npc.Tradeables LIKE '%1%' OR
                 npc.Tradeables LIKE '%2%' OR
                 npc.Tradeables LIKE '%3%' OR
                                npc.Tradeables LIKE '%4%');
```

I want to display the information such as:

| Trader | Items |
| --- | --- |
| Prapor | Weapons, Wearables, Weapon Modifications, Health and Buffs |
| Therapist | Weapons, Wearables, Weapon Modifications, Health and Buffs |

Is there a technique I can use to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! We really need to know what your server is - this kind of functionality is frequently dependent on various "tricks" from the server provider!

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm using Sqlite3

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html GROUP_CONCAT()

Comment: Me again! I should have mentioned this in the first post - can you please provide your tables as DDL (`CREATE TABLE...`) and your data as DML (`INSERT INTO...`) - it helps those who are trying to help you! Even better, do this as a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=43c282ede623b37dd0ba7f862097b0ef), but be sure to include what's in the fiddle here also!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the [GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group_concat/) function on top of your existing query like so:

```
SELECT Trader, GROUP_CONCAT(Items, ',') AS Items
FROM 
(
    select NPC_Traders.Nickname as Trader, Classes.Class as Items
    from NPC_Traders, Classes
    where Items IN (
               select npc.Tradeables
               from NPC_Traders npc 
               where npc.Tradeables LIKE '%1%' OR
                     npc.Tradeables LIKE '%2%' OR
                     npc.Tradeables LIKE '%3%' OR
                                    npc.Tradeables LIKE '%4%')
) AS Subquery
```